# How to run a javascript in a dynamically generated html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a scenario where with jquery mobile i create a listView of pages. I have a number of events in a database , i parse the events in my web page and i create a list view with html pages , one for every event. I also create a unique "subscribe" button inside every page so that the user can subscribe to that event (the ids of the buttons are sub1 , sub2 , sub3 etc..)

The problem is that i dont know how i can access the button id , as i cant see how i could run javascript in any of these dynamically generated pages. What i am trying to do is , IF user is in page of event1 and presses sub1 button , subscribe for that event. But i dont know how many events the database has and that means i dont know how many pages will be created.

Comment: I'm confused -  I don't understand how you can run jQuery but can't run JavaScript.  Could you clarify what you mean?  Thanks.

Comment: construct an appropriate selector http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also give each button an `onclick` method in the html

HTML:

```
<button id="subX" onclick="subscribeEvent(this)">Some Subscribe button</button>
```

JS:

```
window.subscribeEvent = function (element) {
    console.log(element.id);
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/jmRAe/)

Comment: Pleasure - glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

### Use a class to register a click, then get ID as an attribute

Give all the `id=subX` buttons a class `sub-button` then do this:

```
$('.sub-button').click(function() {
    subscribe($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

This will pass the ID of the clicked button to `subscribe` as a parameter.

[This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/36CjA/) prints the ID of the last clicked button to a `div`.

Comment: looks like an elegant solution , but doesnt seem to work for some reason. Are you sure is like this?

Comment: @JohnyJaz Yes, if you have a function called `subscribe` that takes a button ID as parameter, and all your buttons have a class of `sub-button` as well as the ID.

Comment: Everything is exactly as you say. I edited the question take a look at the code if you like. I get the events with some ajax calls and then i do what you say.

Comment: @JohnyJaz See the demo I added, it may help.

Comment: @JohnyJaz Have you included jQuery before your script?

Comment: in the main html page

Comment: @JohnyJaz Can you include your main HTML?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36475/discussion-between-johny-jaz-and-sweetie-belle)